# Is Ethereum 2.0 (Sharding Ethereum) only PoS based? Or a combination of PoW + PoS?

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, proof-of-work, sharding

Does Ethereum 2.0 (Sharded Ethereum) only use PoS (Proof-of-stake) for consensus mechanism ?

Or

Does it use a combination of PoW + PoS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventual 2.0 uses only PoS.

But as 1.0 (the current version) uses PoW there will be some mixture for some time. The current plan for the beginning is to use PoS for every 100th block (https://www.exodus.io/blog/ethereum-proof-of-stake-date/) and PoW otherwise - to test the PoS slowly. The current 1.0 chain will probably be one shard in the new PoS chain for some time.

There is no centralized place to gather information about Eth 2.0 as it's a decentralized system. But a good starting point for (lots of) reading is for example https://hackmd.io/e4cNiocFTiS67j6yJ_XHPw?view or for the actual research you can check https://ethresear.ch/ .

Comment: Is there any official document from Ethereum that confirms it? Thanks

Comment: Modified answer. There is no "official" documentation as it's a decentralized network. Any plans that are currently may change any day but of course current plans are the best known plans.